# Why X.Org is not multi-threaded?

Tags: xorg

I read here (1) that X.Org is not multithreaded. Quoting:

> Certain applications running intensive graphical operations can easily freeze your desktop (a simple easily reproducible example: run Adobe Photoshop 7.0 under Wine, open a big enough image and apply a sophisticated filter - see your graphical session die completely until Photoshop finishes its operation).

I have this problem very frequently in my PC. On Windows (sorry to do the comparison) this does not happen as frequently. The GUI remains somewhat responsive even during intensive computations.

Why was X.Org designed this way?

Are there any plans to address this issue in the future (maybe with alternatives like Wayland, Mir, etc.)?

Currently is there an alternative Linux desktop that, at least partially, overcomes this issue?

1. http://itvision.altervista.org/why.linux.is.not.ready.for.the.desktop.current.html

Answer (score 2):

Possibly related question: ["Is any part of the X.org software multithreaded?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78466/is-any-part-of-the-x-org-software-multithreaded/)

Quote from one of answers:

in E. S. Raymond's book the author quotes .

> The X server, able to execute literally millions of ops/second, is not
>   threaded; it uses a poll/select loop. Various efforts to make a
>   multithreaded implementation have come to no good result. The costs of
>   locking and unlocking get too high for something as
>   performance-sensitive as graphics servers. -- Jim Gettys

As I understand, the client side can be multitheaded, it just depends on implementations. And the same applies to wayland, it's clients can be multi-threaded, from [01.org](https://01.org/blogs/2012/wayland-1.0):

> The client side library is designed to integrate well into toolkit
>   event loops and work in both single-threaded and multi-threaded
>   environments.